# How to align this form exactly in the centre of the division that is holding the form?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a template and trying to align a form exactly in the middle of the division that contains the form. Here's the code as follows:

```
  <!-- ##### Contact Area Start ##### -->
<section class="contact-area bg-img section-padding-100-0" style="background-image: url('img/bg-img/plain.png');">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">

            <!-- Contact Content -->
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
                <div class="contact-content mb-100">
                    <!-- Section Heading -->
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <p>Contact now</p>
                        <h2><span>Get In Touch</span> With Us</h2>
                        <img src="img/core-img/decor.png" alt="mango plant">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Contact Form Area -->
                    <div class="contact-form-area">
                        <form action="index.html" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn famie-btn">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- ##### Contact Area End ##### -->
```

*Here's how the form is looking at the moment on my page :*

[image]

I need to align it exactly in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this class to your div:

```
.box{
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 0.5px solid #DADCE0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can offset your container to the middle of screen by using the [offset classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns). For example, set column container to:

   `<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">`
2. Easiest to use the [horizontal alignment classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment), just change your row to the following;

   `<div class="row justify-content-center">`

edit: incorrectly though `text-center` would help, it won't.

Comment: can you show me the exact syntax to that. I cannot find no text-center class.

Answer (score -1):

`display: flex` can be used in order to center the row after container:

```html
  <!-- ##### Contact Area Start ##### -->
<section class="contact-area bg-img section-padding-100-0" style="background-image: url('img/bg-img/plain.png');">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">

            <!-- Contact Content -->
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
                <div class="contact-content mb-100">
                    <!-- Section Heading -->
                    <div class="section-heading">
                        <p>Contact now</p>
                        <h2><span>Get In Touch</span> With Us</h2>
                        <img src="img/core-img/decor.png" alt="mango plant">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Contact Form Area -->
                    <div class="contact-form-area">
                        <form action="index.html" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn famie-btn">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- ##### Contact Area End ##### -->
```